# How to handle read timeout exception in jersey client 1.8

Tags: java, jersey-client

I am using `jersey 1.8`

to call an external service.
Here is my code.

```
 try{
     ClientResponse response = webResource.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, encodedHashString).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
 }catch(ClientHandlerException che){
   //handelling code here
 {
```

when read timeout exception occurs it gives `ClientHandlerException` and underlying exception is `SocketTimeoutException`. But question here is I can not just say that since its `ClientHandlerException` it is a timeout exception because this exception can happen for other client related errors. 
what can be the exact code to handle it, I need to do some handeling if its a read timeout exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
try {
    ClientResponse response = webResource.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, encodedHashString).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
} catch(ClientHandlerException ex) {
    handleClientHandlerException(ex);
}

private void handleClientHandlerException(ClientHandlerException ex) throws ClientHandlerException {
    if (ex.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
        // handelling SocketTimeoutException code here
    }
    throw ex;
}
```

In `handleClientHandlerException` you also can try something like [ExceptionUtils#getRootCause](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getRootCause(java.lang.Throwable)) from apache commons lang if cause isn't `SocketTimeoutException` to get the root cause.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Throwables.getRootCause](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#getRootCause%28java.lang.Throwable%29) method from guava!